# "AntiSpy" iphone

Tags: ios, swift3, камера

Простите слегка ламерский вопрос - на iphone есть возможность "заблокировать" камеру и микрофон? Типа как на андроиде занять их приложением (сервисом в фоне) и не отдавать пока не наступит время "Ч"?
PS "за такое надо уибивать" и прочее - знаю. Это не вирус. И вопрос в возможности/невозможности, а не в том надо убивать или нет.. Благодарю за понимание :)

Answer (score 1):

В iOS приложения не могут работать долго в бекграунде(за исключением аудио, локации, voip, удаленные нотификации, загрузки и блютус), система сама убивает процесс, до 15 минут вроде если включить нужные флаги в проекте, не помню точно, но не больше. И то, это время может быть меньше в зависимости от того как решит система (будет ли ей хватать ресурсов на активные задания и т.д.) 
Вот тут есть табличка с перечнем процессов [ссылка на гайд](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)
Так что, думаю, ответ на ваш вопрос - "нет".

Comment: Благодарю. Т.е. там вообще невозможно что-то делат ьв фоне? Т.е. (вопрос нмного уходит в другую тему) например приложение периодически опрашивает прибор, или же наоборот, сама что-то шлет (типа банальный gps трекер) - такие приложения в айосе невозвможны? (ну это же бредятина, с точни зрения банальной логики... или как обычно им там в эпл виднее )

Comment: Ошибся немного, но конкретно то что вы спрашивали не выйдет сделать, там порядка 10 процессов в бекграунде могут работать. Основные я добавил в ответ